# Npm/Node hanging on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I am experiencing a scenario where any npm commands are hanging forever here (and I mean no matter how long I wait for real). This happens after some period of usage.

My only workaround for now is to restart the PC (yep.. windows solution!)

I tried to check the running programs but couldn´t find anything abnormal.

I have node v8.9.4, npm v5.6 and windows 10.

--verbose or -npm_debug=1 do no good, as it seems that the npm doesn´t even start. No network trace either on Fiddler.

My firewall is already turned off

After the restart it works fine (for a while).

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried clearing your npm cache? `npm clear cache`. Also, does this happen on all of your node projects or just one? If it is just one, it is probably 1 package causing the issue. I would try removing all packages from your package.json and adding them back in one at a time.

Comment: All of them. Even related things such as nvm also hang, perhaps it could be something global.

I´ll give it a shot on the clear cache.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/18436

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else faces it: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/18436

Appears to be an issue with that "warsaw" program which is used by onlinebank applications here in Brasil.

Uninstalling it did the trick.